# Hadoop 2.2.0 Window 7 build failed Access is denied

Tags: windows, hadoop, build, permissions

I'm trying to build Hadoop 2.2.0 on Windows 7 x64 and it fails at Apache Hadoop Distribuition project with and "Access is denied" message for hadoop-2.2.0-src\hadoop-dist\target\hadoop-2.2.0\bin\hadoop.dll. I've tried to delete the bin folder, to set permissions on various folders in said hierarchy, but it does not work. Also tried running the Windows SDK cmd as an administrator and normal user to no success. Is there anything I can try anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problems when building Hadoop 2.7.1 on win7 x64. I modified the pom.xml of hadoop-dist project and added one line "run chmod 777 *.txt" and it worked.

```
                  echo "Current directory `pwd`"
                  echo
                  run rm -rf hadoop-${project.version}
                  run mkdir hadoop-${project.version}
                  run cd hadoop-${project.version}
                  run cp $ROOT/LICENSE.txt .
                  run cp $ROOT/NOTICE.txt .
                  run cp $ROOT/README.txt .
                  run chmod 777 *.txt <--- Add a line here
                  run cp -r $ROOT/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-${project.version}/* .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with Hadoop 2.4.1 installation on Windows 7 x64. I got the installation working after I first gave permissions and then extracted the sources.

I used following instructions:
https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-2/BUILDING.txt?view=markup

After all environment variables were set and relevant programs installed I did following steps:
1) Create a new folder
2) Set access rights to that folder (I gave all users "Full Control" to the new folder)
3) Extracted the sources to the new folder
4) Run "Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt" as Administrator
5) run command: set Platform=x64
6) run command: mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar -e